# Cypher to find (multiple) "lowest" nodes

Tags: go, neo4j, cypher

**Case:**

I've nodes `Categories` that looks like below and i created a relation from category to parent.

```
CREATE(p1:Categorie {
  id: 2,
  parent_id: 1,
  name: "Kids",
  is_active: true ,
  position: 1,
  level: 1,
})
CREATE(c1:Categorie {
  id: 5,
  parent_id: 2,
  name: "Toys",
  is_active: true ,
  position: 1,
  level: 2,
})

//New root category
CREATE(p2:Categorie {
  id: 9,
  parent_id: 1,
  name: "Holiday",
  is_active: true ,
  position: 1,
  level: 1,
})
CREATE(c2:Categorie {
  id: 12,
  parent_id: 9,
  name: "Water",
  is_active: true ,
  position: 1,
  level: 2,
})


CREATE(c1)-[:CHILD_OF]->(p1)
CREATE(c2)-[:CHILD_OF]->(p2)
```

Then I have products that hase an array of `categorie_ids` like this:

```json
{
    "sku": "abc",
    "name": "Electric boot",
    "categorie_ids": [ 
        1,
        5,
        9,
        12
    ]
}
```

The API gives all the ids back that the product is "in". For me this so much clutter in all the relationships. This example is minimum but in reality this could be up to twenty relations per product.

**Question/Problem:**

I would like to create a relation to the lowest node(s) in the categories. In this case the product has two main categories and thus two bottom categories. So I would like to create a relation to id 12 and 5.

I just can't wrap my head around the cypher query. Can someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically looking at the following query :

> MATCH Categorie nodes where their id is in the given list of ids and those nodes shouldn't be the parent of any other Categorie

Based on your model, you're looking at adding a predicate that Categorie nodes do not have an `INCOMING` relationship of type `CHILD_OF`

```
WITH [1,5,9,12] AS categoryIds
MATCH (n:Categorie)
WHERE n.id IN categoryIds
AND NOT ()-[:CHILD_OF]->(n)
RETURN n.id
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Unfortunately this results in returning all the nodes. As you can see visually in this screenshot: https://ibb.co/qjjR0vL In this case (besides the single nodes) i only wanted the red ones

Comment: @RemcoE33 This answer is actually correct, given the question you provided. But your question gave the wrong relationship type (`CHILD_OF`). Your image shows that the actual relationship type is `CHILD_OF_CATEGORIE`.

Comment: :embarrassing-emoji @cybersam. Thank you!